# Outlook changing height of column in responsive email

Tags: html, email, outlook

This is a html email for marketing purposes for my company. We bought a template from themeforrest and have edited it from there. I've worked out most of the kinks that Outlook has caused, but can't seem to find the source of the problem for this issue.

In one of the sections of the email I have a table with a title section, and another table with two columns divided into their own . When I put the email through Litmus for testing, the right column in the table appears longer than the left. I have inspected and analyzed the code, and each column is identical as far as the tags and attributes go. I am relatively new to coding, so I'm using the MailChimp html editor with preview and the code might not be as clean as it should be.

Here's what I've done:

- All elements in tables with their own
- Declared height for text and spacer containers
- Containers holding text are same height and width ratio
- Spacers above and below are same height and width ratio
- I thought the length of the text might be causing the issue, so I edited the longer text to fit into the same amount of lines. No luck there.
- I tested the section with and without the CSS included above it. Same Problem.
- The only thing I've done to make a real difference was editing the nodes for the titles above the columns. This seemed to change the placement of the column, but not in a beneficial way. And I need the height of the text containers and nodes for the title portion to remain the same, as it is the solution for another Outlook problem I've had that made the green bar expand its' height to the line-height of the  above it.
- Have researched solutions from CampaignMonitor and EmailonAcid

Here is the code for the section:

```
<table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="bfbfbf" mc:repeatable="promail" mc:variant="testimonials section" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;font-size: 14px;border: 0;">

<tbody><tr>
    <td align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
        <table border="0" align="center" width="800" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="ffffff" class="container800 blue_bg" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;font-size: 14px;border: 0;">

            <tbody><tr><td height="50" style="font-size: 50px;line-height: 50px;border-collapse: collapse;">&nbsp;</td></tr>

            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                    <table border="0" align="center" width="590" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container590" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;font-size: 14px;border: 0;">

                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td align="center" style="color: #666666;font-size: 14px;font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;font-weight: 700;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;line-height: 24px;border-collapse: collapse;" class="outlook white_color" mc:edit="testiheader">

                                <!-- ======= main header ======= -->

                                <div class="outlook editable_text" style="line-height: 24px;">
                                    <span class="outlook text_container">

                                        TESTIMONIALS

                                    </span>
                                </div>

                            </td>   
                        </tr>

                        <tr><td height="12" style="font-size: 12px;line-height: 12px;border-collapse: collapse;">&nbsp;</td></tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                                <table align="center" width="50" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="0893d3" class="blue_bg" style="background-color: rgb(9, 187, 77);border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;font-size: 14px;border: 0;">
                                    <tbody><tr><td height="2" style="font-size: 2px;line-height: 2px;border-collapse: collapse;"></td></tr>
                                </tbody></table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr><td height="12" style="font-size: 12px;line-height: 12px;border-collapse: collapse;">&nbsp;</td></tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" style="color: #000000;font-size: 28px;font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;font-weight: 300;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;line-height: 28px;border-collapse: collapse;" class="outlook main-header white_color" mc:edit="testisubheader">

                                <!-- ======= main header ======= -->

                                <div class="outlook editable_text" style="line-height: 28px;">
                                    <span class="outlook text_container">

                                        What Do Our Customers Say?

                                    </span>
                                </div>

                            </td>   
                        </tr>

                        <tr><td height="55" style="font-size: 55px;line-height: 55px;border-collapse: collapse;">&nbsp;</td></tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td style="border-collapse: collapse;"> 
                                <table border="0" width="285" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="09bb4d" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;border-radius: 5px;font-size: 14px;border: 0;" class="container590">

                                    <tbody><tr><td height="25" style="font-size: 25px;line-height: 25px;border-collapse: collapse;">&nbsp;</td></tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                                            <table border="0" width="230" height="168" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;height: 168px; font-size: 14px;border: 0;" class="container580"> 

                                                <tbody><tr>
                                                    <td align="left" style="color: #ffffff;font-size: 14px;font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;line-height: 24px;border-collapse: collapse;" class="outlook text_color" mc:edit="testitext1">
                                                        <!-- ======= section subtitle ====== -->

                                                        <div class="outlook editable_text" style="line-height: 24px;">
                                                            <span class="outlook text_container">

                                                                This is an extremely good company. My agent Brent was excellent, and very timely in explaining the terms, and getting my loan ASAP. Thank you, very much, I will Highly recommend you!<br><br>

                                                            </span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <tr><td height="25" style="font-size: 25px;line-height: 25px;border-collapse: collapse;">&nbsp;</td></tr>

                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                                                        <table border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;font-size: 14px;border: 0;">
                                                            <tbody><tr>
                                                                <td style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                                                                    <a href="" style=" border-style: none !important; display: block; border: 0 !important;" class="editable_img"><img editable="true" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/5ed1d967731cd6ee36b103443/images/735223a6-a047-4079-8a5e-ffdd8d30e29b.png" style="display: block; width: 50px;" width="50" border="0" alt="team img" mc:edit="testiimg1"></a>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td style="border-collapse: collapse;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                                                                <td style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                                                                    <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;font-size: 14px;border: 0;">
                                                                        <tbody><tr>
                                                                            <td align="left" style="color: #444444;font-size: 16px;font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;line-height: 22px;border-collapse: collapse;" class="outlook title_color" mc:edit="testisubtitle1">
                                                                                <!-- ======= section text ====== -->

                                                                                <div class="outlook editable_text" style="line-height: 22px">
                                                                                    <span class="outlook text_container">

                                                                                        Linda

                                                                                    </span>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </td>   
                                                                        </tr>

                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td align="left" style="color: rgb(68, 68, 68);font-size: 14px;font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;line-height: 22px;border-collapse: collapse;" class="outlook blue_color" mc:edit="testisubtitle2">
                                                                                <!-- ======= section text ====== -->

                                                                                <div class="outlook editable_text" style="line-height: 22px">
                                                                                    <span class="outlook text_container">

                                                                                        Happy customer

                                                                                    </span>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </td>   
                                                                        </tr>

                                                                    </tbody></table>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody></table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody></table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr><td height="25" style="font-size: 25px;line-height: 25px;border-collapse: collapse;">&nbsp;</td></tr>

                                </tbody></table>

                                <table border="0" width="2" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;font-size: 14px;border: 0;" class="container590">
                                    </table>

                                <table border="0" width="285" align="right" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="09bb4d" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;border-radius: 5px;font-size: 14px;border: 0;" class="container590">

                                    <tbody><tr><td height="25" style="font-size: 25px;line-height: 25px;border-collapse: collapse;">&nbsp;</td></tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                                            <table border="0" width="230" height="168" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;height: 168px; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;font-size: 14px;border: 0;" class="container580"> 

                                                <tbody><tr>
                                                    <td align="left" style="color: #ffffff;font-size: 14px;font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;line-height: 24px;border-collapse: collapse;" class="outlook text_color" mc:edit="testitext2">
                                                        <!-- ======= section subtitle ====== -->

                                                        <div class="outlook editable_text" style="line-height: 24px;">
                                                            <span class="outlook text_container">

                                                                This company is very dedicated to their customers! Very organized! Always quick and orderly with every step of the process! Truly a great company to work with! Great people to talk to, who you can understand and never feel lost in the process!

                                                            </span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <tr><td height="25" style="font-size: 25px;line-height: 25px;border-collapse: collapse;">&nbsp;</td></tr>

                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                                                        <table border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;font-size: 14px;border: 0;">
                                                            <tbody><tr>
                                                                <td style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                                                                    <a href="" style=" border-style: none !important; display: block; border: 0 !important;" class="editable_img"><img editable="true" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/5ed1d967731cd6ee36b103443/images/735223a6-a047-4079-8a5e-ffdd8d30e29b.png" style="display: block; width: 50px;" width="50" border="0" alt="team img" mc:edit="testiimg2"></a>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td style="border-collapse: collapse;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                                                                <td style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                                                                    <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;font-size: 14px;border: 0;">
                                                                        <tbody><tr>
                                                                            <td align="left" style="color: #444444;font-size: 16px;font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;line-height: 22px;border-collapse: collapse;" class="outlook title_color" mc:edit="testisubtitle3">
                                                                                <!-- ======= section text ====== -->

                                                                                <div class="outlook editable_text" style="line-height: 22px">
                                                                                    <span class="outlook text_container">

                                                                                        Sarah

                                                                                    </span>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </td>   
                                                                        </tr>

                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td align="left" style="color: rgb(68, 68, 68);font-size: 14px;font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;line-height: 22px;border-collapse: collapse;" class="outlook blue_color" mc:edit="testisubtitle4">
                                                                                <!-- ======= section text ====== -->

                                                                                <div class="outlook editable_text" style="line-height: 22px">
                                                                                    <span class="outlook text_container">

                                                                                        Happy customer

                                                                                    </span>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </td>   
                                                                        </tr>

                                                                    </tbody></table>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody></table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody></table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr><td height="25" style="font-size: 25px;line-height: 25px;border-collapse: collapse;">&nbsp;</td></tr>

                                </tbody></table>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr><td height="50" style="font-size: 50px;line-height: 50px;border-collapse: collapse;">&nbsp;</td></tr>

        </tbody></table>
    </td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
```

Here is an image of what it looks like when rendered through Outlook:
[img]https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQBnf.png

I'd really appreciate any help you can provide. - Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to give the `<tr>` the desired height where the green sections/columns are in?

Comment: I have. So such luck. Also, I realized I linked the wrong image, the correct image is now in the post. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling your problem is coming from how you structured the layout for the area with two columns. In the HTML, there are three tables sitting right next to each other within one td - shouldn't all of those tables be wrapped in another table, and each table be wrapped in a td to help ensure the layout is correct. I don't think I have ever just put multiple tables next to each other in an email - anything with columns should be set up with proper tds.

Also, you can kinda replicate the layout issue in your browser if you apply a different width and height to the empty middle table - perhaps Outlook is giving that table different dimensions, therefore messing up your layout.

Comment: Would wrapping all the columns in another table affect the responsiveness of the email?

Comment: Well you may have to ensure your particular responsive CSS accommodates the layout change, but my understanding of basic responsive emails is that they should break down to one column, where tables and td become display block and width 100%, so regardless of the additional table everything should stack as one column.